# how to save application users created in jboss in a database or serialize them

Tags: jboss, migration, upgrade

I want to migrate the management and application users created in jboss using add-user.bat utility while upgrading the jboss version.

For that i was thinking if it is possible to store the users created in jboss in a database or may be something like serializing them while creating and update the jaas cache of the jboss server at the time of boot up.

Is there any way to export the user list from an existing jboss installation?

So can anyone please help me with either of the above?

Or may you please suggest me which should be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way of exporting application/management users from the JBoss server. But all the application and management users created for jboss will present in `application-users.properties` and `mgmt-users.properties` files.

You can get usernames with the encrypted password in the following format

username=HEX( MD5( username ':' realm ':' password))

e.g.
admin=2a0923285184943425d1f53ddd58ec7a

All the roles and groups for the users will present in `application-roles.properties`
and `mgmt-groups.properties` files.
Location for above files :

- standalone mode: JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/
- domain mode: JBOSS_HOME/domain/configuration/